# Mapping predicates and propositions in DLV/Prolog

Tags: logic, predicate, zebra-puzzle, answer-set-programming

I'm having trouble understanding how to go about something

Imagine i have 3 donkeys, and each donkey has a favorite cloth, and plays at its favorite playground.

If i give these donkeys constraints on which playground could be its favorite playground for example playground A, B, or C, or even give a constraint of what could possibly be its favorite cloth through a hint such as Donkey humprhey's favorite cloth is definetly not a tshirt how would i go about it.

I.E. My idea of it so far is

```
cloth(tshirt).
cloth(socks).
cloth(hat).


playground(a).
playground(b).
playground(c).


donkey(alphred).
donkey(pumba).
donkey(sylvester).


%Would mapping be something like this?
donkeys(Donkey, Playground, Clothing) v donkeys(Donkey, Playground, Clothing) donkeys(Donkey, Playground, Clothing) :- donkey(Donkey), playground(Playground), cloth(Clothing).

%how would i add constraints based off this, such as alphreds favorite cloth is a tshirt but he hates playground b?

cloth(tshirt) :- donkey(alphred).
~playground(b) :- donkey(alphred).

%how do i also make sure no two donkeys have the same cloth and playground in the answer set?
```

Im using dlv as my answer set solver

Comment: I did it in dlv, however dlv is based off prolog and they are similar

Comment: No problem man, the documentation is hard to grasp which is why i'm having trouble. http://www.dbai.tuwien.ac.at/proj/dlv/tutorial/ the example with the map coloring is the on i'm trying to  follow

Comment: You could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482224/clingo-assert-partial-constraints/23570874 for ideas