# Murder puzzle in ASP

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

So under the tag prolog I found this puzzle ([original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65272839/prolog-murder-mystery)) and I thought: this would be even better in ASP. So I put this here as a question for anyone who wants to solve a puzzle with me. I will answer this question as soon as I found a solution myself, and I would be happy to compare my code with yours. Thank you.

> jean was killed on Tuesday; the only suspects are:
>
> Luc, Paul, Alain, Bernard and Louis.
>
> The rules to follow are:
>
> 1. The murderer is somebody who has a motive to kill jean, who owns a
>    gun, and who does not have an alibi for Tuesday.
> 2. An alibi provided by a person who is not trustworthy is not
>    accepted.
> 3. Somebody has a motive to kill jean if he has a special interest in
>    killing jean or he wants revenge.
> 4. Somebody has a special interest in killing jean is he is the
>    beneficiary of jean’s fortune, or if he owns money to jean, or if jean
>    surprised him committing a crime.
>
> Here are the facts established by the investigation:
>
> Luc has an alibi for Tuesday given by Bernard
>
> Paul has an alibi for Tuesday given by Bernard
>
> Louis has an alibi for Tuesday given by Luc
>
> Alain has an alibi for Thursday given by Luc
>
> Alain is not a trustworthy person
>
> Paul wants to take revenge on Jean
>
> Luc wants to take revenge on Jean
>
> Bernard is the beneficiary of Jean’s fortune
>
> Jean is the beneficiary of Louis’s fortune
>
> Louis owns money to Jean
>
> Luc owns money to Jean
>
> Jean has seen Alain committing a crime
>
> Luc owns a gun
>
> Louis owns a gun
>
> Alain owns a gun

Comment: This a variation of a Zebra puzzle and you can see techniques for solving this in ASP in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482224/clingo-assert-partial-constraints

Comment: @vukk thanks for the link. In my opinion this puzzle more than zebra because people can lie; which makes it even more appealing to solve in ASP

Comment: @vukk oh you are right. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
person(luc; paul; alain; bernard; louis).

alibi(luc,tuesday,bernard).
alibi(paul,tuesday,bernard).
alibi(louis,tuesday,luc).
alibi(alain,thurday,luc).
ntw(alain).
revenge(paul,jean).
revenge(luc,jean).
beneficiary(bernard, jean).
beneficiary(jean, louis).
owns(louis,jean).
owns(luc,jean).
seen(jean,alain).
gun(luc;louis;alain).

{murderer(M):person(M)} == 1.
murderer(M) :- person(M), motiv(M,jean), gun(M), not validalibi(M,tuesday,_).
validalibi(M,D,A) :- alibi(M,D,A), tw(A).
{ntw(P);tw(P)} == 1:- person(P).
motiv(P,O) :- revenge(P,O).
motiv(P,O) :- interest(P,O).
interest(P,O) :- beneficiary(P,O).
interest(P,O) :- owns(P,O).
interest(P,O) :- seen(O,P).

#show tw/1.
#show murderer/1.
```

My solution assumes that there is only one murderer and every person is either trustworthy (`tw/1`) or not (`ntw/1`). The output is

```
Answer: 1
murderer(alain) tw(bernard) tw(luc) tw(paul)
Answer: 2
murderer(alain) tw(bernard) tw(luc) tw(paul) tw(louis)
Answer: 3
murderer(alain) tw(bernard) tw(luc)
Answer: 4
murderer(alain) tw(bernard) tw(luc) tw(louis)
SATISFIABLE
```

Which more or less states: if there is only one murderer then it is Alain and it does not matter if Paul or Louis are trustworthy.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this problem , and and this is my solution . I hope it will help you and if does , so please click on check and rank solution.

```
alibi(luc,bernard,tuesday).
alibi(paul,bernard,tuesday).
alibi(louis,luc,tuesday).
alibi(alain,luc,thursday).
notrust(alain).
revenge(paul,jean).
revenge(luc,jean).
benefit(bernard,jean).
benefit(lean,louis).
owns(louis,jean).
owns(luc,jean).
crime_seen(alain,jean).
gun(luc).
gun(louis).
gun(alain).
special_interest(X,jean):- benefit(X,jean);owns(X,jean);crime_seen(X,jean).
true_alibi(X):- alibi(X,Y,tuesday), \+ notrust(Y).
motive(X,jean):- special_interest(X,jean);revenge(X,jean).
murderer(X,jean):- gun(X),motive(X,jean),\+ true_alibi(X).
solve(X):-murderer(X,jean).
```

Comment: which clingo version do you use? Mine does nor accept \+ as not.

Comment: Also please provide your output.